# Rails routes with not-equal-to constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like to add a not-equal-to constraint on my routes rule. Specifically, I would like to assert that a parameter should not equal to something.

For instance, in the following code:

`get ':menu/:submenu', constraints: { # put something here }`.

I'd like to impose that `:submenu` is not equal to `abc`. I've tried to write `submenu: /(?!abc)/` as a constraint, but that somehow affects all the other params. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is possible to achieve this. I just did not use the right regex. I will post the solution later in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

7 years later...! Here is the regex you would want (and which I also needed).

```
constraints: { submenu: /(?!abc).+/ }
```